# Now have tag "ski" - should fix?

Tags: support, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

Even though we have a real English [skiing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing) tag synonym as part of [winter-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-sports) somebody has created a pseudo English* tag [ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ski) that has now been used three times.

Since only a moderator can make [ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ski) a synonym of [winter-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-sports) and only people with enough "tag score" can nominate and vote towards it becoming a synonym, there's nothing I can do but report it here.

I am also not opposed to breaking out the synonym [skiing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing) into its own tag now that the site has grown so much and either making [ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ski) a synonym of that or just burninating it. But this also requires moderator action.

<sup>* "Ski" actually is correct English of course for questions asking about a single ski rather than a more usual pair, about ordering somebody to ski, etc. But not make good tag.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ski) is now synonym to [skiing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skiing), and they are both synonyms to [winter-sports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-sports). We can possibly remove the synonym, though this will cause some old questions to float to the top of the current questions list. I'll make some assessment and will provide an update how many posts will be affected.